# c# calculating digit before floating points

Tags: c#, for-loop

I'm trying to calculate the number of digit before the floating points. for example

input: 123.4

expected output: 3
my actual output: 5

I'm sure there is something wrong with the digit.equals(".") since the program does not break out of the loop.

this is my code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(HowManyDigit(123.4));
    }

     public static Int32 HowManyDigit(Double number)
        {
            string x = number.ToString();

            var counter = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                var digit = x[i];
                //Console.WriteLine(counter);
                if (digit.Equals("."))
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            return counter;
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? And does ToString() actually produce **`123.4`** or does it maybe produce **`123,4`**?

Comment: The reason you are having this problem is because the char `'.'` will never be equal to the string `"."`.  if your logic was `if(x[i] == '.')` you would see the result you want.  However, this is not the best way of getting the digit count, check the answers for far better ways

Comment: Console.WriteLine(x.GetType()); --> System.String and Console.WriteLine(x[3]); ----> .

Comment: @randomNameGenerator `x` is a string, but what is `x[i]`...

Comment: @maccettura it's a char. so Equals method does not work on a char comparison?

Comment: A char is not a string, so when you check if `char.IsEqualTo(string)` what do you imagine would happen?  They are different data types even though they effectively "look" the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `x.IndexOf('.')` this will be your answer

Comment: Actually `IndexOf`

Comment: you are right! however, do you know why that digit.Equals(".") does not work? I'm still confused why It does not break.

Comment: because that is a string and x[i] is a char use .Equal('.')

Comment: may be you should use char, ('.')

Answer (score 3):

The reason your code does not work breaks down to this logic:

```
var digit = x[i];
if (digit.Equals("."))
{
    break;
}
```

The *char* `digit` will **never** be equal to the *string* `"."`

If you change your code to:

```
//Note that I use a char, indicated by ''
if (x[i].Equals('.'))
{
    break;
}
```

Or simply:

```
if (x[i] == '.')
{
    break;
}
```

Either of those two methods will give you a drastically different result from your current code.

That being said, this method is not really the best way of doing what you want.  You can simply use `IndexOf()` to get the exact number you want:

```
public static int HowManyDigit(double number)
{ 
   return number.ToString().IndexOf('.');
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O34KvT)

Comment: noted and thank you! one final question, so if we want to compare a char, we have to use == and for string, we use Equals() ?

Comment: @randomNameGenerator you can use `digit.Equals('.')` just fine but note that I am indicating a _char_ `'.'` **not** a _string_ (`"."`)

Answer (score 2):

Just compute the logarithm of base 10 and then convert to integer with floor.

```
n = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(x))+1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
if (digit.Equals("."))
```

With this:

```
if (digit.Equals('.'))
```

Now your output should be 3.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a LINQ solution:

```
double number = 123.4;
var result = number.ToString().TakeWhile(x => char.IsDigit(x)).Count();
```